# GROUP BY Optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, group-by

Hey. I´ve got these two tables in a 1:n relation.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `de_locations` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`user_id` int(11) default NULL,
`author_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`district_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(150) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`description` tinytext collate utf8_unicode_ci,
`lat` double NOT NULL,
`lng` double NOT NULL,
`stars` double default '0',
`comments` mediumint(9) default '0',
`flag` tinyint(4) default '0',
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
KEY `flag` (`flag`),
KEY `rating_district` (`district_id`,`stars`,`comments`),
KEY `rating_city` (`city_id`,`stars`,`comments`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `de_location2category` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`location_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cat_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `rel` (`location_id`,`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
```

A location could be placed in more than one category.

For example:

Location: "Pizza Hut"
Categories: "Italian Food", "Fast Food"

These categories are child categories of the parent category food.

Now I want to select all the locations within the category food.

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.description, a.street, a.hnr, ROUND(a.stars) as stars, a.comments, a.lat, a.lng
FROM de_locations as a 
INNER JOIN de_location2category as b
ON b.location_id = a.id
WHERE b.cat_id BETWEEN 0 AND 100 
AND a.city_id = 1000 
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.stars DESC, a.comments DESC
```

I need the GROUP BY because I don´t want duplicate locations if they where related to more than one category. But this query builds an temporary table and uses filesort. If I leave the GROUP BY everything is fine, but I need it …

Have I got to add another index? Or is anything wrong with my scheme? 
How would you solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: "But this query builds an temporary table and uses filesort."  So what?  That's the way relational databases work.  What's wrong with that?  How else do you propose it removes duplicates?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html "In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the ORDER BY, although it still uses indexes to find the rows that match the WHERE clause. These cases include the following: *You use ORDER BY on different keys: SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY key1, key2;*"

Comment: "What´s wrong with that?" The performance. In a simple SELECT a GROUP BY not always force temporary tables. Isn´t there a way to achieve that in this case?

Also the index "rating_city" is not used with GROUP BY.

Comment: Hey Dav. Yes I have read the "order by optimization" docu. But I am not able to find a solution. Is it simply not possible? Or could I achieve better performance by changing the index or the SELECT?

Thanks so far

Comment: It's pretty black and white: if you use more than one key for ordering, then you're going to be using filesort.

Comment: Yes. But I am searching for different solutions. I tested to ad the column "de_locations.id" to the index "rating_city" so that I not have to order by more than one key, but that´s not changing anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the query is slow. No need to worry about temporary and filesort, but why the query is slow.
Add the output of the EXPLAIN {yourquery} so we can check what exactly happens.

Or you can also try a subquery:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.description, a.street, a.hnr, ROUND(a.stars) as stars, a.comments, a.lat, a.lng
FROM de_locations as a 
WHERE 
a.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT b.location_id FROM de_location2category as b WHERE b.cat_id BETWEEN 0 AND 100)
AND a.city_id = 1000 
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.stars DESC, a.comments DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `DISTINCT` a.id ?

Comment: same result as GROUP BY: temporary tables and filesort

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much a given since you're sorting by multiple keys. It's just that DISTINCT describes what you're actually trying to achieve far better then GROUP BY.

Comment: Do I got you right that the problem is that I use the index "rel" in the WHERE clause and the index "rating_city" in the ORDER BY clause?

And because of that I didn´t have a chance to only change the index? 

So I have to live with temporary tables and filesort?

Sorry, got some language problems ...